# Making colnames by number and character

Tags: r

I have a very big matrix I want to put colnames as cell1, cell2, et,.. but I get error

```
> colnames(new.dat)
NULL
> View(new.dat)
> dim(new.dat)
[1]     34 263086
> colnames(new.dat)=make.names(c(1: 263086, "cell"))
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
> colnames(new.dat) <- paste0("cell", seq_along(new.dat))
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
>
```

[image]

any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really test your code:

```
make.names(c(1: 5, "cell"))
[1] "X1"   "X2"   "X3"   "X4"   "X5"   "cell"
```

This is obviously wrong.

Better:

```
colnames(new.dat) <- paste0("cell", 1:ncol(new.dat))
```